# using 'this' pointer for two constructor

Tags: c++, constructor, this

Consider this class implementation:

```
template <class Impl>
class LSQ {
   public:
      LSQ(O3CPU *cpu_ptr, IEW *iew_ptr);
      IEW *iewStage;
  class DcachePort : public Port
      {
         protected:
           /** Pointer to LSQ. */
           LSQ *lsq;
         public:
           DcachePort(LSQ *_lsq) 
            : Port(_lsq->name() + "-dport", _lsq->cpu), lsq(_lsq)
           { }
   };
   ...
 };

 // default code 
 template <class Impl>
 LSQ<Impl>::LSQ(O3CPU *cpu_ptr, IEW *iew_ptr)  
   :  cpu(cpu_ptr), iewStage(iew_ptr), dcachePort(this), 
 {
   ...
 }

 // default code
 template<class Impl>
 std::string
 LSQ<Impl>::name() const    
 {
    return iewStage->name() + ".lsq";   
 }
```

So `DcachePort()` takes 'this' which is actually

```
 LSQ(O3CPU *cpu_ptr, IEW *iew_ptr);
```

Now I added my own constructor:

```
 template <class Impl>
 class LSQ {
    public:
       LSQ(O3CPU *cpu_ptr, IEW *iew_ptr);   // default code
       LSQ(O3CPU *cpu_ptr, Fetch *f_ptr);   // added by me
       IEW *iewStage;
       Fetch *fetchStage;
   class DcachePort : public Port
       {
          protected:
            /** Pointer to LSQ. */
            LSQ *lsq;
          public:
            DcachePort(LSQ *_lsq)  // default code
             : Port(_lsq->name() + "-dport", _lsq->cpu), lsq(_lsq)
            { }
   };
   ...
  };


  // added by me
  template <class Impl>
  LSQ<Impl>::LSQ(O3CPU *cpu_ptr, Fetch *f_ptr)   // added by me
   : cpu(cpu_ptr), fetchStage(f_ptr), dcachePort(this)
  {
  }
```

Problem is, 'this' in my constructor is

```
  LSQ(O3CPU *cpu_ptr, Fetch *f_ptr)
```

and when it enters  `DcachePort(this)` and then `name()`, it tries to execute

```
  return iewStage->name() + ".lsq";
```

but in my constructor, `iewStage` is not initialized. Instead `fetchStage` is used.

How can I fix that?

Answer (score 1):

`DcachePort` has a dependency on `iewStage`, so if you are going to continue to use the existing `DcachePort` constructor implementation, you will have to pass in `iewStage` as a third constructor parameter.

(Or edit the existing constructor to pass in `fetchStage` as a third parameter.)

Alternatively, rewrite `LSQ::name()` so it uses information from `fetchStage` instead of `iewStage`. (and if you can't, then you'll still have to pass in `iewStage` as a constructor parameter`)

---

One final suggestion: If you can pass the ["is-a"](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Is-a) test, you could subclass `LSQ`, doing something like this (not sure if I have the template syntax right):

```
template <class Impl>
class MyLSQ : public LSQ<Impl>
{
     Fetch *fetchStage;
     MyLSQ(O3CPU *cpu_ptr, IEW *iew_ptr, Fetch *f_ptr);
}


template <class Impl>
MyLSQ<Impl>::MyLSQ(O3CPU *cpu_ptr, IEW *iew_ptr, Fetch *f_ptr)  
  : LSQ(cpu_ptr, iew_ptr), fetchStage(f_ptr)
{
}
```

For the "is-a" test to pass, any instance of MyLSQ has to be able to be used like an LSQ for any of LSQ's methods (including the constructor) but you can add on extra state/behavior, and override any of LSQ's virtual methods.

Comment: can you paste a snippet? both constructors call `DcachePort` with `this`, but port() can not distinguish that

Comment: how can you possibly have two constructors, one of which initializes iewStage but not fetchStage, and the other which initializes fetchStage but not iewStage? It sounds like you need one constructor that initializes both.

Comment: @comment2: not necessarily... I don't want to change the default code as far as I can. So the default code initialize its own parameters and I want to initilize my own parameters.

Comment: For each object, you can only execute one constructor. You can choose from more than one alternative constructor, but you can't execute more than one constructor in sequence. So you have to initialize all the parameters that must be initialized at construction time from any constructor call.